# How to ECDH Implement in Microservices

Tags: kubernetes, cryptography, microservices

I have a problem when I want to encrypt decrypt data by use the same key in every services.I use ECDH Method to encrypt decrypt data between client and server. I have a exchangeKey service to gen Key send back to client and obtain pubkey from client and then compute share secret key to get common key but I have a problem when I want to use the same key in other containners in k8s to encrypt decrypt data from a same client.
so what is the best practice to let others container knows what key they gotta use to do encrypt or decrypt to or from the same client in every containers after compute share secret key from exchange key service.

Comment: I think this is more suitable for https://security.stackexchange.com/. I'd personally use a data key to encrypt, and then *wrap* that key with a secret key that is separately established by the different parties. Or, if the data doesn't need to be protected at rest, I'd use TLS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming, it is about designing a security model for a specific usage scenario.

Comment: sorry I didn't know before that I have to ask this question in another domain. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After I research, I got a solution that I should Use Redis Containers to store session data like key that I want to share to others containers and when others container want to encrypt or decrypt they will request to Redis container to fetch the get each client key . But I'm not sure about a performance to read write from redis container. But redis do store in the ram. I guess that it would be better than store in DB